# Wrong object when creating a dynamic view in OpenERP

Tags: python, field, odoo

I am new to OpenERP development and I am trying to create a dynamic view which will create a checkbox for each element of the `categories` table which in created by the `categories()` class in my `module.py` file.

Now inside my `users()` class I created the function `fields_view_get` with the following code

```
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False,submenu=False):
    result = super(categories, self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id, view_type, context, toolbar,submenu)
    school_obj = self.pool.get('sim.categories')
    result['arch'] = '''<field name="father_name" />'''
    return result
```

As you can see my code is not even close to generating the dynamic fields, I am still far away of doing that but even this test gives me the following error

```
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

I figured out that if I change `categories` in the `result = ...` line for `users` the error will go away giving place to new ones, but why would I want to inherit the `users` class inside the `users` class.

Any tip on what might be wrong or what I am missing will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this error by adding `if view_type == 'form':` before `result['arch'] =`

It looks like when viewing the `tree` view the `result` was called triggering the error and as that was the first view which appear when I click the menu link, it was triggered each time.

Comment: do you have any idea for creating dynamic field for openerp-7